# Variable gets expanded in a loop with condition, how to "reset" when certain condition met?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, initialization, environment-variables, reset

I have a loop that scans through each data point and checks for a certain condition:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    if x == False:     #1
       if a.loc[[i]] > b.loc[[i]]: #2
          value = "yes"
          test = 1 / y.loc[[i]]
       ...

    if value == "yes":
          test_2 = test * z.loc[[i]]
          x = True

    elif x == True: #3
      ...
          test_3 = test - test_2 * e.loc[[i]] #4
          x = False
```

and so on.

The variable at questions are here test and resulting from that test_2 and test_3. These should just be 1x1 variable, however, the condition #1 and #2 are met throughout the loop causing that test gets expanded to 1xN. such that test_3 below does not work anymore.

How can I make: the loop or the conditions to "reset" the variable test, as soon as my conditions #3 and #4 are met such that when the loops starts at 1 again, I will get a 1x1 variable test? thank you.

edit 1: maybe to make it more clearly. variable test becomes a series for the iterations in the loop (whenever the condition is met). What I need is to get the new value (from the next iteration) to overwrite the previous value instead of appending it.

Comment: Is the code indentation correct? What branch does the "elif x == True" belong to? I would say it should belong to the first "if", but it stands under the "if value == "yes":"

Comment: please apologize my late reply. My current solution is to 1) always the last row value of the variable AND to reset the variable, i.e. test_2 = 0 after each statement.